# error installing eclipse enterprise edition on windows 7 64bit

Tags: eclipse

I have tried to install eclipse enterprise edition multiple times but evry time this problem occured. please give me soltion for this error

failed to load the JNI shared library "c:\Program Files(x86)\java\jdk1.6.0_16\bin..\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll"

Answer (score 0):

Your version of eclipse should match the version of JDK, either both 64 or both 32